# Calculate total by summing price multiplied by quantity for all items

Tags: php, sum, resultset, multiplication, cumulative-sum

I'm currently doing making a website that sells games as a project but im having problems calculating the sum for the price of the games.

I have this loop which displays the games added into the basket.

**cart.php**

```
<?php
    $count = 0;
    while ($count < $numrow)
    {
    $row = $results -> fetch_assoc();
    extract($row);
    echo"<div>";
    echo"<div class='recommended_games'>";
    echo "<img src='images/".$gameIMG."' />";
    echo "</div>";
echo '<div class="price_tag">';
echo '<div class="price_tag" name="price" method="POST">£'.$gamePrice. '</div>';
echo'</div>';

echo '<div id="update_form"><form action="updatebasket.php" method="POST" name="updateform">';
echo '<select name="quantity" id="quantity" />';
echo      '<option value="1">1</option>';
echo      '<option value="2">2</option>';
echo      '<option value="3">3</option>';
echo      '<option value="4">4</option>';
echo      '<option value="5">5</option>';
echo      '</select>';
echo '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name="gameid" id="gameid" />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="update" />';
echo '</form>';
echo '<div class="quantity_update">';
echo '<form action="remove_item.php" method="POST">';
echo     '<input type="hidden" value="'.$gameID.'" name="gameid" id="gameid" />';
echo     '<input type="submit" value="Remove Item"  />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';
echo '</div>';             
                        
                        
                            
 echo"<img class='box1' src='Images/Grey-Banners.png' />";
 echo"</div>";
 $count = $count + 1;   
                        
 }     
 echo '<div id="delete_all">';
 echo '<form action="delete_cart.php" method="POST">';
 echo    '<input id="hide_button" type="submit" value="Clear All"  />';
 $a=array($gamePrice);
 echo array_sum($a);
 echo '</form>';
 echo '</div>';
 ?>
```

**this is where im trying to calculate the total price**

```
$a=array($gamePrice);
echo array_sum($a);
```

Comment: and what exactly is not working? `array_sum` is a php function and should work as expected

Comment: Wheres the loop? Whats the output of `$gamePrice`?

Comment: `$a=array($gamePrice);` is outside your loop so you will only get the last value of `$gamePrice`. Put it inside the loop above, next to `$count = $count + 1;` -> `$a[]=$gamePrice`

Answer (score 2):

The reason this doesnt work, is because `$gamePrice` never is an array (unless you didnt provide all code). In the loop, it gets set to a new value, after the loop only the last one is stored.

Based on some hints in your code, I guessing this is a cart and you're looping through the cart. An easy way to get a total is like this:

```
$total = 0;
while( $itemsThatWeLoop){
    // Some code here
    $total+= $gamePrice*$quantity;
}
```

You add a variable which increments with the product's price

---

To explain the while-only-last-value-saved:

```
$i=0;
while( $i<=10){
    $i= $i+1;
}
echo $i;
```

Will give 10. All other iterations `$i` gets set to a new value. The original value is not saved

Comment: hiya thank you for the reply i have edited my code above to provide all of the code

Comment: im quite new to php so im not quite sure what i replace the 'itemsthatweloop' with? because i tried placing that with gameID but it came up with errors, sorry for such a question but still new to php :/

Comment: I made a edit. Please not that if you want something with `$i`, we normally use `foreach`, but this fitted better to your question

Comment: ahh okay thank you so much for your help, i used your code and just tried it out and works (kinda). the only problem now is that it only displays 0 even when there are items in the cart whereas previously i only had error messages appear which is a good starting point i guess